# Error: spawn ENONT appearing randomly (streams related)

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, stream, pipe

I am using Nodejs streams to download a file from S3 and pipe directly to a local folder as a writable stream. Once the local file is saved, I do some additional processing to re-size the local file into multiple versions and re-upload to S3.

The code below properly downloads the file from S3 and stores in a local folder. I have confirmed this works.

```
var readable = request(path)
        , writable = fs.createWriteStream('files/images/' + fileName);
    var localPath = 'files/images/' + fileName;

winston.log('info', "About to start download: " + asset.fileType);
readable.pipe(writable)
    //once the file is saved, start processing it
    .on('error', function(error){
        winston.log('error', error);
    })
    .on('finish', function () {
        winston.log('info', "file downloaded");
        series(localPath, sizesKey.shift(), respond);
        readable.end();
        writable.end();
    }).on('error', function(error){
        winston.log('error', error);
    });
```

When I run my script on my local machine, everything works properly, and the rest of my script continues without incident.

However, when running from an Amazon EC2 LINUX with Node v.10.10 the error below is thrown after the above code runs, but not always at the same time. For example, the error might appear during the re-sizing, after a successful re-sizing, or even during an S3 upload, which all occur after the code above should be completed.

My guess is that I'm not closing the stream properly and its just shutting the door on me so to speak. Nonetheless, I'm shooting in the dark now.

Here is the error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by breaking the streams into distinct objects so that you get a better idea of where the error is coming from. Perhaps it is the `series(...)` function?

Also if you have winston configured to log to a file, but the file is not available that could be giving you the error. Try removing winston and replacing with `console.log` to see if that fixes the problem

```
var readable = request(path),
  writable = fs.createWriteStream('files/images/' + fileName);
var localPath = 'files/images/' + fileName;

// winston.log('info', "About to start download: " + asset.fileType);
console.log('about to start download: ' + asset.fileType)

readable.on('error', function(error) {
  console.error('error from readable stream')
  console.dir(err)
})

writable.on('error', function(error) {
  console.error('error from writable stream')
  console.dir(err)
})

writabale.on('finish', function() {
  // winston.log('info', "file downloaded");
  console.log('file downloaded')
  // I'm not sure what this series function does
  // series(localPath, sizesKey.shift(), respond);

  // these end methods have already been called after the "finish" event fires
  // readable.end();
  // writable.end();
})

// it is best practice to setup all your event handlers before piping streams together, so the pipe call is moved to the bottom here
readable.pipe(writable)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem turned out to be that GraphicsMagick was not not properly installed and when I called methods from that package later down in the script, it crashed. Why the error didn't appear at the time those commands were called is another concern altogether.